# How can i stop vs code from making .ipynb files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

When i run **example**.ipynb file in vs code, it saves me a lot of files like:

**example**-caloifdf-498s-a54d-sdj8-caksjnbrhn83.ipynb

**example**-a60c6s44-9fax-4747-a9da-as9876fg34r8.ipynb

etc...

in the same folder where **example**.ipynb is in.

Questions:

1. What are those files?
2. How i can i stop vs code from making them\put them in another path if they are relevant?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

That should actually be a bug. It's supposed to delete those files. There a consequence of us using jupyter under the covers to run your kernel.

This bug here should resolve it when we fix it:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6510

Answer (score 0):

.ipynb files aren't created by vs-code, they are [jupyter notebook](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ipynb) files generated when working with jupyter notebooks. They don't appear in anaconda or other IDEs which have built-in jupyter notebook support because there is no need to interact with the underlying .ipynb file directly.